# How to insert Primary key using Django Models?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, django-views

i have set  Primary key in my Django Models and but When i am inserting data into MongoDB database ,the primary key is not inserted.by default Django is inseting primary key but in my case its not.i Don't know what i am Doing Wrong Here.i am using below code

My Model.py

```
   class CategoryModel(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) #if i don't use this line,django should insert primary by default.i my other app its inserting by default
        category_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

when i insert data into my CategoryModel,the primary key is not inserted.i am using Following code to insert data

Views.py

```
CategoryModel.objects.create(
            category_name =request.POST['category_name']
        )
```

Here,category_name  is inserted but Primary key is not inserted.I don't know what is the issue.i Will be thankful if any one can help me with this issue.

Comment: Django 3.2 does not have an official MongoDB database backend. Nor is one listed in the 3rd-party backends mentioned in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/ . It would be useful to know what you are using. (It's not obvious to me whether a document database should have the same automatic-primarykey behavior we expect from an ACID database.)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = CategoryModel()
a.category_name = request.POST['category_name']
a.save()
```

and ID you must use some other name for id because id is default django field

```
id_out = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=False, db_index=True, unique=True, editable=False)
```

Comment: Its showing error 'can't have more than one auto-generated field'

Comment: It's probably because you named your field "id" and by default it implemented the `Autofield` "id". (Don't forget to also makemigrations and migrate)

Comment: `BigAutoField` must set `primary_key=True`

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of id you're looking for, I typically use uuid4:

```py
from uuid import uuid4
from django.db import models

def gen_uuid() -> str:
    """Return a str representation of a uuid4"""
    return str(uuid4())


class CategoryModel(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(
            unique=True,
            primary_key=True,
            default=gen_uuid,
            max_length=36,
            help_text="Example: c8daa3ac-3dd0-44e9-ba2a-b0cbd1c8d8ae.",
    )
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

This allows to customize your ID. However if you are sure to use UUID like above I'd recommend this implementation as it uses the proper field:

```py
from uuid import uuid4
from django.db import models

class CategoryModel(models.Model):
    uid = models.UUIDField(
            unique=True,
            primary_key=True,
            default=uuid4,
            help_text="Example: c8daa3ac-3dd0-44e9-ba2a-b0cbd1c8d8ae.",
    )
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

As it is explained by the Autofield doc, you do not need to set your id if you wish to have the default id behavior: [Autofield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#autofield)

It should insert your id automatically if you don't specify anything.